# Good way to index a table

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a table of four columns: ID, ID_version, name, address.
One ID can have many ID_version. Current example has 3 values of ID, one of them has two ID_version. In total, there are four combination: 1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 3-1. All combination have approximately the same number of rows.

My query is:

```
select address from table where ID=1 and ID_version=1;
```

I want to applied index strategy to improve above query in term of explain plan and consistent gets from autotrace.

First, I applied the organization index on all columns of that table with order ID, ID_version, name, address. The explain plan showed that this table was fast full scanned using this these primary keys. And the cardinality is extremely high.

Then I changed the order of indexing: ID_version, ID, name, address. The explain plan showed this table was range scanned using these primary keys, but the cardinality is still high.

Then I combined ID and ID_version into one column of string (now table has only 3 columns) and applied the same index strategy as the first attempt. Now the explain plan showed that table was range scanned and the cardinality and value of consistent gets is extremely low compare to the above solutions.

Can someone help me to explain such behavior? Is there any other index strategy when having ID and ID_version as separate columns but performance in cardinality and consistent gets is good?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create an index on the two columns that are in your "where" clause predicate, and make sure to update statistics on the table. Also be aware that if the SQL optimizer thinks it is more efficient to do a full table scan it will do so regardless of the indexes - the volume of data in your table will make a difference in the plan.

Comment: `create index ix1 on table (ID=1, ID_version);` will improve the performance of that particular query. No need to combine both columns into a single one.

Comment: `create index idx1 on table (id,id_version)` ... done. And if that defines uniqueness, make it your PK or at least `create unique index`...

Comment: Indexing `id_version` separately will provide no benefit, unless you have queries that are predicating *only* the `id_version` column, which is very unlikely. Since all such use of that column would be in conjuction with another (more important) predicate on `id`, you want the two in the same index, with the more important `id` column listed first.

Answer (score 0):

A column named `ID` is supposed to be the table's unique ID, i.e. there is exactly one row in the table per ID. A column named `ID_version` is supposed to be the unique ID of a table named `version`.

Neither is the case here, so let's rename the two columns. You are dealing with historicized contact information. If a person's name changes with marriage or divorce or an address changes when a person moves, a new contact version is created in the table.

```
create table contact
(
  contact_number          number(10)          not null,
  contact_version_number  number(2)           not null,
  address                 varchar2(4000 char) not null,
  name                    varchar2(200 char)  not null,
  primary key (contact_number, contact_version_number)
);
```

The table's primary key is the combination of the contact number (that can be assigned to a person) and the version number (for storing multiple versions of a contact for name and address changes). By making these two columns (ID and ID_version in your original table) the primary key, the DBMS creates a unique index with the same columns in the same order. Thus we can quickly access a contact (by contact_number) and its versions (by its contact_version_number). The index wouldn't help, if we queried by contact_version_number alone, but that should never happen, because a contact_version_number 1, 2 or 3 or whatever will only have a meaning for a given contact_number.

In your query you select by contact_number and contact_version_number, and the index will help finding that one row almost immediately. If you queried by contact_number only, the index would still suffice to get a person's contact history very fast.

With only five rows in your table, though, it doesn't make sense for the DBMS to run through an index. It will be quicker to just read the whole table. So, don't be surprised when the DBMS decides for a full table scan. Once the table grows, the index will get used and you will greatly benefit from it.

Comment: Naming conventions vary. Using `ID` at all is a bad idea because it's so uninformative and requires constant vigilence to properly alias when joining to other tables with the same column name but different meaning. As to it being the PK, any surrogate key in a type-2 or versioned table can be repeated across rows, requiring the historicizing/versioning column to complete the primary key definition. Quite common, really.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I agree that column ID is specifically for unique index only. I also realize the problem is that I defined ID as a varchar and then use number to find value. In that case, it needs to perform to_number on the index column, hence it's no longer the index column for searching.